# Batch file: program output in different folder

Tags: batch-file, lua, batch-processing, luac

So I'm using luac to compile some `.lua` into `.lub` recursively through a batch file.

I'm also having an issue that the output of the luac (same name as the `.lua`, but with `.lub` extension) is not going to the folder where the `.lua` was found.

I've used:

```
for /r %%r in (*.lua) do luac5.1.4.exe -o "%%~nr.lub" "%%r"
```

and the `.lub` of a `.lua` in a deeper folder is outputted in the root folder.

What should I change in the script so it outputs inside the `.lua`'s location folder?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this situation simply altering the end of the script. It now looks like this:

```
for /r %%r in (*.lua) do "luac5.1.4.exe" -o "%%~pnr.lub" "%%r"
```

Now the batch will output to `%%~pnr`, which serves as the file name and its path, excluding the extension, so I could add the `.lua` at the end, solving this little issue.